# How to popup the video or jpeg or swf in iframe?

Tags: jquery, jsp, iframe, popup

I am working with jsp page with custom portlet in liferay and need to create one popup in which my video will play (like preview). I have tried with JQPlayer and video.js but it isn't working with embed url somehow.

I don't know much more about jQuery and CSS. I have tried with some demo code available with Google but not achieving success..

I have my `vid_url` in one variable in my `view.jsp` page.and one `iframe` which have link on that `vid_url`...

This is my jQuery to popup but my URI doesn't work in that jQuery (I had tried to open a another page or even tried with embed URL but now working out).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showPopup() {
      AUI().use('aui-dialog', 'aui-io', 'event', 'event-custom', function(A) {

        var dialog = new A.Dialog({
                title: 'Popup Title',
                centered: true,
                draggable: true,
                modal: true,
                width: 600,
                xy: ['center',10],


            }).plug(A.Plugin.IO, {uri: '/jsps/preview.jsp',}).render();

            dialog.show();

      });
};
```

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

see that youtube(Iframe)
this is best.
[see this](http://fancybox.net/home)